# Converting a column in a data.frame to numeric type to calculate mean values in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm new to coding and I tried my best to find an answer but nothing worked. So I hope you can help me:
I have data from a 96-well plate and I managed to convert it into tidy data by using the Plater package. Than it looks like this:

```
> print(PlaterTest)
# A tibble: 96 x 4
   Wells `Amino acid position` Mutant Fluorescence
 * <chr>                 <chr>  <chr>        <int>
 1   A01                   D46      A          456
 2   A02                   D46      Y          856
 3   A03                   D46      R          356
```

This data.frame contains some blank values. I want to calculate the mean and subtract it from all the other values. So calculate the mean I found the following code:

```
meanblank <- mean(PlaterTest[PlaterTest$`Amino acid position` == "blank", "Fluorescence"])
```

But than I get:

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(PlaterTest[PlaterTest$`Amino acid position` == "blank",  :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

So I tried to transform the "Fluorescence" column to a numeric type by using many differnt approaches and finally found this:

```
PlaterTest$Fluorescence = as.numeric(as.character(PlaterTest$Fluorescence))
```

So now I get:

```
> print(PlaterTest)
# A tibble: 96 x 4
   Wells `Amino acid position` Mutant Fluorescence
 * <chr>                 <chr>  <chr>        <dbl>
 1   A01                   D46      A          456
 2   A02                   D46      Y          856
 3   A03                   D46      R          356
```

I also found the following code line with the given result:

```
> sapply(PlaterTest, class)
          Wells Amino acid position              Mutant        Fluorescence 
    "character"         "character"         "character"           "numeric"
```

But I still can't calculate the mean value using the code shown above, since it still gives me the same error message. I think I have some troubles with the differnet data types. I hope you can help me with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP's dataset is a `tibble` and `tibble` don't have default `drop=TRUE` to drop the dimensions when there is only a single column selected.  So, basically, it is still a `tibble`

```
PlaterTest[PlaterTest$`Amino acid position` == "blank", "Fluorescence"]
# A tibble: 2 x 1
#  Fluorescence
#         <int>
#1          856
#2          356
```

and `mean` won't work with `data.frame` or `tibble`.  According to `?mean`

```
mean(x, ...)
```

> x - An R object. Currently there are methods for numeric/logical
>   vectors and date, date-time and time interval objects. Complex vectors
>   are allowed for trim = 0, only.

So, it needs a `vector`.  Therefore, the option would be to extract the 'Flourescence' as a `vector` and subset it based on the 'blank' values in 'Amino acid position' column

```
PlaterTest$Fluorescence[PlaterTest$`Amino acid position` == "blank"]
#[1] 856 356

mean(PlaterTest$Fluorescence[PlaterTest$`Amino acid position` == "blank"])
#[1] 606
```

---

Also, we can use the `tidyverse` methods

```
library(dplyr)
PlaterTest %>%
         filter(`Amino acid position` == 'blank') %>%
         summarise(Mean = mean(Fluorescence)) %>%
         pull(Mean)
```

#### data

```
PlaterTest <- structure(list(Wells = c("A01", "A02", "A03"), `Amino acid position` =
 c("D46", 
 "blank", "blank"), Mutant = c("A", "Y", "R"), Fluorescence = c(456L, 
 856L, 356L)), .Names = c("Wells", "Amino acid position", "Mutant", 
 "Fluorescence"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```